# Using custom ArgumentMatcher

Tags: java, mockito

Suppose I have an interface with method named `call`, which takes the parameter of `ServiceRequest`. In `ServiceRequest` there are fields named `fieldA` and `fieldB`. I would want to mock the response of calling this method and return different mock response result if only the value of `fieldA` in ServiceRequest is different.

I have the following codes like follow (with reference to https://www.baeldung.com/mockito-argument-matchers), however it returns null pointer exception. What goes wrong here ?

```
@Mock
private Service service;

@Test
public void testCustomMatcher() {
    ServiceRequest req1 = new ServiceRequest();
    req1.setFieldA(1);

    ServiceRequest req2 = new ServiceRequest();
    req2.setFieldA(2);

    when(service.call(argThat(new CustomArgMatcher(req1)))).thenReturn("mockResp1");
    when(service.call(argThat(new CustomArgMatcher(req2)))).thenReturn("mockResp2");
}

public class CustomArgMatcher implements ArgumentMatcher<ServiceRequest> {
    private ServiceRequest left;

    public CustomArgMatcher(ServiceRequest s) {
        this.left = s;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean matches(ServiceRequest serviceRequest) {
        return left.getFieldA() == serviceRequest.getFieldA();
    }
}

interface Service {
    String call(ServiceRequest request);
}

public class ServiceImpl implements Service {

    @Override
    public String call(ServiceRequest request) {
        return "sample";
    }
}

public class ServiceRequest {
    private int fieldA;
    private int fieldB;

    public int getFieldA() {
        return fieldA;
    }

    public void setFieldA(int fieldA) {
        this.fieldA = fieldA;
    }

    public int getFieldB() {
        return fieldB;
    }

    public void setFieldB(int fieldB) {
        this.fieldB = fieldB;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I see two problems:

1. you didn't call `MockitoAnnotations.initMocks()` anywhere. Usually this goes into a method annotated with `@BeforeAll` or `@BeforeEach`. Probably you just didn't copy it to the example.
2. An ArgumentMatcher has to behave somehow like `equals(...)`: it must accept also `null` as an argument without throwing an exception.

See the [JavaDoc](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.mockito/mockito-core/latest/org/mockito/ArgumentMatcher.html) of `matches`:

> The method should **never** assert if the argument doesn't match. It should only return false.

Try to use this:

```java
return (null != serviceRequest) && (left.getFieldA() == serviceRequest.getFieldA());
```

As a `null` ServiceRequest object never will match anything, it will return `false` in that case.

Comment: The examples I saw on the net and especially the ones you linked from Baeldung only use the ArgumentMatchers in `verify` and not in stubbing with `when` - so due to an implementation detail this could be the reason why they work by coincidence.